# My info@ email address keeps sending SPAM mails

Tags: spam, hacking

Since somewhere in april my info@ email address is being used to send SPAM emails. I first noticed it when I received a 'Mail Delivery System' email with the message that an email couldn't be sent because the mail had "550 High probability of spam".

So, I contacted my website hoster (Versio).

Seeing that the emails that were being sent out on the local host (127.0.0.1) had no authentication, they advised me to change the password I used with that email address. (I use apple mail to send my mails, so it had a different sender host) See the image below. The only ones I've sent myself are the 4th of May ones.
[image: The SPAM emails from may]

I changed all passwords I use for my website / the website hoster, just to be safe. Used Safari-recommended passwords. 
This didn't stop the sending of the emails, so Versio thought that there was a script on my website that was sending those emails. They ran a few scans but couldn't find any infected files.

Since I'm not that happy with the support they've given me, I hope to find some tips here. Can I do anything myself to stop these emails?

[image: Email that I've received]

Comment: We cannot determine what's wrong without physical access to the server. But the story is the same: either your site is vulnerable or your server has been compromised. Have a static analysis done on your code to look for vulnerabilities and if you are using out of the box software like Joomla upgrade to the latest version. You may need to completely remove your site and re-upload a clean copy from your computer to be sure no infected files are included.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate and think these are actually bounce back emails. iow, mail sent by others with the questioner's return email address. @Lisa, nothing you can do about that and it's not your fault.

Comment: @Rob If that's the case, am I at risk of being blacklisted?

Comment: @Lisa No because those services are aware of bounce back and can tell where the mail really did originate from the headers. Your email won't be in those headers as the origin. Bounce back email is a common occurence unfortunately.

Comment: @Rob I've added the email (as image in the OP), can you tell me if that indicates such a bounce back email? And if those are 'bounce back emails', why are they listed in my 'sent' emails, seen in the image above?

Comment: Since these appear in your email log with a local IP address, they're likely being sent through a server-side script, most probably using PHP. Therefore you may want to disable the _mail()_ function in your PHP configuration since you're only sending email through a remote client application. If you're using cPanel for your hosting account, follow the instructions at the bottom of this thread:  https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-can-i-restrict-send-mail-without-username-and-password.343121/#post1384842  You could also configure your mail server to block local IP's too.

Comment: There are other steps you can take as well, for example with cPanel see:  [How to Prevent Email Abuse](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Prevent+Email+Abuse). Unfortunately, it appears that you're already blacklisted in some databases, see [this](http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/imandragrafie.nl/) report, which is why you're receiving failed delivery messages. Once you lock down your mail server, you'll need to go about the process of getting removed from these (click on the links in that report for more info on each, you don't need to sign up for the info btw). Good luck!

Comment: @dan OK, so by disabling the mail() function the emails will stop? But when I want to include a contact form in the future (and thus sending 'myself' an email [from local IP I assume?] with the contact info that a user wants to send), isn't that using the mail() function?
I have DirectAdmin v.1.50.0 by the way. Can't seem the get logged on to the phpmyadmin settings, so I have to contact my provider for that.

Comment: Quite possibly, and it's quick to do. You could use another server-side language like Perl for a contact form in the future. Ideally, you should locate the source though. For DirectAdmin, this should help:  [My server is sending spam. What do I do?](https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=455). If you have backups of your site prior to this occurring, you might want to do as John recommended and just wipe the server clean and upload your site again. However spending some time finding the source, and learning about how to protect your server might help to prevent this from occurring again.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @dan! I will follow the tips in the link you gave, despite the blacklisting it's kind of interesting to learn about all this.